# How to determine the number of conditions that define a set in a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So previously I was asked to find  the dimension of W where W was the set of anti-symmetric matrices in V=M3x3. I found that the dimension was 3. They then asked me to compute the codimension of W in V and determine the number of conditions that define W in V? I'm confused because I thought they were both the same thing? Can someone help me to determine the number of conditions that define W in V?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a $3$-by-$3$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ then the condition
$A=-A^T$ translates into nine conditions on the $a_{i,j}$, namely
$a_{11}+a_{11}=0$, $a_{12}+a_{21}=0$, $a_{13}+a_{31}=0$, etc.

But you will find these relations are not all independent. Throw
out as many redundant relations as you can. The number of relations
remaining will be the codimension.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Could you elaborate a bit more?